# Web service nHibernate configuration issue

Tags: nhibernate, service, configuration, web

I have a C# .Net Web Service.  I am trying to use nHibernate to access my database.  I also have a C# .Net web app using nHibernate to access the db.  The web app works great.  However, the Web Service does not.  Here is my error message

```
The ProxyFactoryFactory was not configured.Initialize 'proxyfactory.factory_class' property of the session-factory configuration section with one of the available NHibernate.ByteCode providers.
Example:
<property name='proxyfactory.factory_class'>NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>
Example:
<property name='proxyfactory.factory_class'>NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of nhibernate are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the hibernate.cfg.xml files the same for both apps? It seems the service config file is missing the property mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another Stackoverflow post.  My bad, I didn't save the link.  But, the answer was to add a reference to NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.  I'll try to find the post that educated me